# How do you use the Object type in interface builder?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

In interface builder there is available type of object called "Object".

I have tried to use this to wire up a view with a property pointing to one of these objects.
I have set the class on Object in interface builder to a custom class. I don't need to set any other properties on this custom class. Basically my desired behaviour is that if that property is set then the view will call a method on it during its lifecycle.

When the view is inflated from the nib file however, my property on the view remains nil.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: May be you would explain what you want to do? We will suggest you the best approach.

Comment: Have you declared in your view (or view controller) a property + `IBOutlet` with the same type as the custom class of your nib object? Have you linked them in Interface Builder/Xcode? If so, upon loading the nib that object of a custom class should have been instantiated and the property in your view/view controller should be pointing to that object.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to create a framework of re-usable behaviours that I can attach to views in interface builder without having to resort to code.

Comment: Do you mean that your custom class object from XIB file is wired to a property (e.g. nonatomic, retain one) in your view controller AND it does not get initialized - i.e. is nil?

Comment: @delirus - yes. I think it is something to do with there being two top level objects in the nib and perhaps initWithNibName discards the second one?

Comment: @Ian: can your custom class be instantiated with regular semantics: `[[MyClass alloc] init]`? Asking because recently I had a similar problem with a singleton not ready to work with NIB unarchiving and it was `nil`. And is your class, as Bavarious points out, an `IBOutlet` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that:

- if you added your custom object in Interface Builder like shown on [this video](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CustomObject.html); AND
- if you connected it to a properly defined property in your view controller (e.g. `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyClass *anObj;` and synthesized it in *.m file; AND
- if you didn't override `+alloc` and `-init` of your custom class in a
  strange way (IB objects get instantiated via alloc and init calls AFAIK - someone please correct me if I'm wrong)

your object should not be `nil` after the nib file was unarchived in runtime. If I meet above conditions for my objects in IB, they are not `nil`.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. The property was being set but I was looking for it too early in the lifecycle. I thought it would be available after initWithCoder was called on the view but it wasn't until initWithCoder on the object was called that it was available. It seems obvious now.

Comment: Not quite what I thought, but actually I needed to be checking in awakeFromNib. RTFM me!